# Why Python .py file size increasing after converting into .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have installed `pyinstaller` to convert python `.py` file into executable `.exe` file. My python file is of about 32 KB and after converting into executable file its size is increased to 17 MB. Why the size has been increased so high and how to reduce it.

The following are the import statements I am using in my python file:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui   
import os  
from os import system as sh  
import mysql.connector  
import base64  
from mysql.connector import Error
```

Comment: Try setting up a virtual environment and install only the required dependencies for your python script and check your file size after that !

Comment: The documentation is quite good at explaining why your file is so big. Read the manifest that `pyinstaller` produces. That will give you a much more explicit explanation than we could.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that when you freeze your python script (i.e. convert it to exe), all of the dependencies have to be bundled along with your 32 KB script.

Updating the setup configuration can help to avoid including unnecessary parts of your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for responce  How do i update setup configuration?

Comment: Sandeep I recommend reading up on the topic a little bit more, it should be clear what configuration I mean once you've read the documentation. Try to understand what is happening when you freeze your script and it will become really clear why the program is the size it is.